# Symbol’s value as variable is void: false when run element-of-setp

Tags: variables, emacs, scheme

Following SICP's instruction, I rewrite its intersection-set as:

```
(defun intersection-set (set1 set2)
  (cond ((or (null set1) (null set2)) '())
        ((element-of-setp (car set1) set2)
         (cons (car set1)
               (intersection-set (cdr set1) set2)))
        (t (intersection-set (cdr set1) set2))))
(defun element-of-setp(x set)
  (cond ((null set) false)
        ((equal x (car set)) t)
        (t (element-of-setp x (cdr set)))))
(intersection-set  (list 1 2) (list 2 3 4))
```

Running it reports the following error:

```
element-of-setp: Symbol’s value as variable is void: false
```

However, `element-of-setp` on its own seems to work properly:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
(defun element-of-setp(x set)
  (cond ((null set) false)
        ((equal x (car set)) t)
        (t (element-of-setp x (cdr set)))))
(element-of-setp 1 (list 1 2 3))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: t
```

What's the problem?

Comment: there is no `false`, instead you have `nil` or `()`

Comment: The error might be trivial, helps are not. Could please transmit the comment to answer. @picklerick

Comment: I'm sure you do know this, but SICP was written for Scheme, not Emacs Lisp, and there are significant differences between the two languages.  You shouldn't be expecting code from one to Just Work in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, `element-of-setp` on its own seems to work properly:

Unfortunately, the test you used did not cover all the possible cases.

If you try instead:

```
(element-of-setp 5 (list 1 2 3))
```

Then the function is going to reach the case where the list is empty, and in that it will evaluate `false`, which is most likely undefined; as stated in the comment, boolean values in Emacs-Lisp are represented by `nil` and non-`nil` values (atoms).